# Need an img-tag over another img-tag from a JS slider

Tags: javascript, image, slider

So I tested some free sliders out there; simple JS scripts, but they seem to use img-tags.
The problem is, that I have something like a badge, and that has to be in the foreground.

What I dont get .. it does not matter in what order I am arranging them; just two images like:

```
<img style="margin-top:-100px;" src="images/slider_image.png">
<img style="margin-left:-30px;" src="images/badge.png">
```

I tried to surround them with divs, giving them a z-index.

Both are surrounded by a div-tag.

So how can I make sure to have a siple JS slider, whilst the badge is always on top ?
I was searching for a slider that uses a div with "background-image:url()" because then it is actually working.

or maybe there are other solutions ?

// edit:
Oh and I also tried to update the badge source with jQuery like $('#badge').attr("src","someimage")
because I thought it could be a problem that JS is updating the slider image after the badge, but did not help

Comment: Position them absolutely and use z.index to place one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint; just got it.
I set the badge to position:relative and that made the effect already working ... thanks anyway ! :)